# Get/Set as different types

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I'd like to define a variable that will accept a string in the SET, but will then convert it to an Int32 and use that during the GET.

Here the code that I currently have:

```
private Int32 _currentPage;

public String currentPage
{
   get { return _currentPage; }
   set 
   {
      _currentPage = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest an explicit `Set` method:

```
private int _currentPage;

public int CurrentPage
{
    get
    {
        return _currentPage;
    }
}

public void SetCurrentPage(string value)
{
        _currentPage = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
```

As a side note, your parse method may do better like this:

```
if (!int.TryParse(value, out _currentPage)
{
    _currentPage = 1;
}
```

This avoids the formatting exceptions.

Comment: a string property returning an int.

Comment: Why would you have a discreet method for setting that takes an argument that's of the same type as the property being set? The example in his question makes more sense. There's nothing wrong with having code in a setter. 

If your method took an argument of a different type (say, int) then it would make sense for it to be separate from the setter.

Comment: @Tangled2 - It makes perfect sense. The only other option is to use object which needs to be constrained anyway. This option allows complete compile time type safety.

Comment: @John Gietzen: Then perhaps you meant for the CurrentPage property in your example to be an Int, not a String.

Comment: @John Gietzen: I saw your ninja edit. ;) It's fixed now, ignore my previous comments.

Comment: @Tangled2: Well, I was hoping nobody saw, but by the time you commented, I had fixed it. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Be aware that this is really really bad idea to have a property get & set being used against different types.** May be couple of methods would make more sense, and passing any other type would just blow up this property.

```
public object PropName
{
    get{ return field; }
    set{ field = int.Parse(value);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is the way it needs to be.  There are no automatic conversions like you're seeking.

Comment: Well, I'd argue that he may want to handle invalid (other than null) data in the set, but he may also have good reasons for not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the magic get and set blocks, you have no choice but to take the same type you return.  In my opinion, the better way to handle it is to have the calling code do the conversions and just make the type an Int.